# Add empty page with razor syntax in empty website in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor, visual-studio-2013

I am facing a problem. I want to add an empty page using razor syntax in an empty website in visual studio 2013 but I can't do it. In the empty website, when I create a folder and right click on it and choose:

- Add > Add New Item

then it does not give me an option of Empty page(razor v3) with C#.

Please tell me what should I do?

Comment: What is the type of your project - ASP.NET or MVC or ASP.NET with Razor?

Comment: My project is an ASP.NET Empty WebSite and I am adding empty page with razor syntax (cshtml) in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had same problem but i did one thing...

1. all steps same from `new ...>website...>empty ..>`
2. after open an empty go to solution explorer - >right click ->go little down from bar and click on manage NuGet Package
3. click on online which is mentioned on your left...it will search for packages
4. then....>**MICROSOFT ASP.NET WEB PAGES, INSTALL THIS PACKAGE BY CLICKING ON IT
5. THEN GO TO PAGE 3 DIRECTLY AND GO TO BOTTOM OF THAT THEN YOU FIND MICROSOFT ASP.NET WEB PAGES WEB DATA, INSTALL THIS PACKAGE ALSO BY CLICKING ON IT.
6. THEN COME BACK TO YOUR PROJECT AND THEN ADD NEW ITEM, THEN YOU FIND (EMPTY RAZOR 3)